# How to get my passport back from the US Consulate?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Upon the US Consulate's request, I sent my passport for visa issuance on July 1st., and until now I haven't received it back!!! I need my passport urgently to apply for a visa to participate in a conference in India. What should I do? I emailed the Consulate but got no answer!

Comment: The US Consulate in Jerusalem. I applied for DS 160 (Non-Immmigrant Visa. Number: AA0053BTQA.  CSC ID: 2008925667.

Comment: My question is how to contact the Consulate because my visa status is AD (Administrative Processing), and I need my passport to travel to India on August 7.